# Conditional formatting inconsistent

Tags: microsoft-excel

Why won't my IsNumber conditional formatting work consistently? 
My Excel sometimes does this with conditional formatting on the simplest formulas.  It will only capture some things, not all.  How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It works for me so I don't think it's your formula.  However, since I'm not getting any skipped cells I can't duplicate your result.  Check if your `Applies to` range is correct.  If the range starts at anything other than `H2` you have a problem.

Comment: @Susan nothing wrong with the Formula,, I'm sure that the problem is Range Selection, & Pick the very First Cell from the Range to be highlighted. Suppose Range is `A2:A100` then your formula should `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Voicemail",$A2)`. ☺

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error — it is consistently shading
the cell *above* the one that contains the word “voicemail”. 
I guess that you are applying the formatting to cells starting at `H1`,
but the formula is looking at `H2`. 
Probably the simplest fix
is to change the formula to reference `H1` instead of `H2`.